# I'm trying to edit a column but rather than updating the colum a new column is being added to it

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I have a table named tasks in my database named cakephp1.
I've written this code in the controller:

```
 function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid Task');
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'), null, true);
    }
    if (empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data = $this->Task->find(array('id' => $id));
    } else {
        if ($this->Task->updateAll(debug($this->data))){
            $this->Session->setFlash('The Task has been saved');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'), null, true);
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The Task could not be saved.
                                        Please, try again.');   
        } 
    } 
 }
```

I'm new to cakephp and this is my example which I am trying out. Please do help me out. What can I do to make the column be updated ?

Answer (score 0):

To update a record you can use save function, and in `$this->request->data` provide id of recode that you want to update. Also `$this->data` is deprecated, and maybe doesn't work, You should use `$this->request->data`.

for example if your $this->request->data is:

```
array('id' => 10, 'title' => 'My new title');
```

By below controller code title of record with id=10 will be updated.

```
function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid Task');
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'), null, true);
    }
    if (empty($this->request->data)) {
        $this->request->data = $this->Task->find(array('id' => $id));
    } else {
        if ($this->Task->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('The Task has been saved');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'), null, true);
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The Task could not be saved.
                                        Please, try again.');   
        } 
    } 
 }
```

Also You should read [this documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html) to understand how you should save(insert, update).